# MongoDB writing query to calculate percent change

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to writing queries in MongoDB.

I am trying to calculate the percent change of a rating of a movie between its current rating and its most recent previous rating. I want to sort by decreasing percent change.

The previous ratings are stored in a field "changelog", and the most recent previous rating is in the last index of the "changelog" array.

Here is what the collection looks like:

```
"changelog": [{
        --Earliest Version--
        "Title": "Foo",
        "Director": "Bar",
        "Genre": "Action",
        "rating": {
            "$numberDouble": "3.45"
            }
        }, 
        {
        --Most recent previous version of this movie, the one I want--
        "Title": "Foo",
        "Director": "Bar",
        "Genre": "Action",
        "rating": {
            "$numberDouble": "4.96"
            }
        }],

--here is current movie info--
"Title": "Foo",
"Director": "Bar",
"Genre": "Action",
"rating": {
    "$numberDouble": "4.99"
    }
```

Now, I am attempting to write the query which creates a "percent_change" field and sorts by it in decreasing order. I first slice the changelog to just get the last element.

My problem is with accessing the last rating in the changelog array.
The error is "Cannot subtract double by array", so the `"$last_changelog.rating"` is returning an array with a single element, but I do not know how to just get the double itself.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
    {"$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "rating": true,
      "changelog": true,
      "last_changelog": {"$slice": ["$changelog", -1]}
        }
    },
    {"$project":{
        "_id":"$_id", 
        "rating": "$rating",
        "percent_change": {

            # more arithmetic is needed
            "$subtract": ["$rating", "$last_changelog.rating"]}, # error is here, doesn't get correct previous rating value.
        }
    },
    {"$sort": {"percent_change": -1}},
])
```

**NOTE:** I need to use aggregate() here because I am working in a visualization software Metabase, and that is the only query they support.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    /** Create a new field `changePercent` which is `rating of lastElem - rating of secondFromLastElem %` 
     * `$slice` will give you rating value in an array, using `$arrayElemAt` to convert value in array to a value
     */
    {
      $addFields: { changePercent: { $subtract: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ { $slice: [ "$changelog.rating", -1 ] }, 0 ] }, { $arrayElemAt: [ { $slice: [ "$changelog.rating", -2 ] }, 0 ] } ] } }
    },
    /** sort on new field in descending order */
    {
      $sort: { changePercent: -1 }
    },
    /** Remove newly create field from output */
    {
      $project: { changePercent: 0 }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8Si0HqPu5Ku)

**Update :** Instead of using `$slice` you could just use `$arrayElemAt`, Only difference would be if there is only one element in `changelog` array then `$arrayElemAt` would not return anything on `-2` which makes `$subtract` return `null` on field `changePercent` - shouldn't be the case if you wanted to show `changePercent` field in response. Where as `$slice` will return same element even with `-1` or `-2` upon a single element in `changelog` array which leads to `changePercent : 0` good if you wanted the value to be out in response  :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
      $addFields: { changePercent: { $subtract: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$changelog.rating", -1 ] }, { $arrayElemAt: [ "$changelog.rating", -2 ] } ] } }
    },
    {
      $sort: { changePercent: -1 }
    },
    {
      $project: { changePercent: 0 }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MyGDtvA3f_Q)

**Ref :** [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)